# which c++ free lib to use to capture microphone sound and save it to wav

Tags: c++, audio, capture, microphone

i saw i have 2 major lib's ( mybe i wrong )
1. port Audio
2. openAl + cAudio wrapper
what is easer and faster to use for cross platform ?

Answer (score 0):

[Bass Audio Library](http://www.un4seen.com/) is the other one I found good, it's smaller, so might fit better for this simple task.

[FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/) is very versatile and used by several "big" computer games. It's more than capable.

Comment: i need it to be free for commercial use

Comment: I haven't used it. But I did (and do) use Qt and it's generally very high quality.

Comment: i use Qt also but i didnt used QtMultimedia